# Problem installing a provisioning profile

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a problem adding the provisioning profile, I already downloaded it but when I added it to XCODE 10 it does not let me choose another value that is not automatic, I do not know why this happens

I have already tried to create a new one from my Apple Developer account but I can not add it

This is my error:

Seccion 15 is automatically signed for development, but a conflicting code signing identity iPhone Distribution has been manually specified. Set the code signing identity value to "iPhone Developer" in the build settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the project editor.

And where I choose the signature and the profile I have this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code Signing Style is set as Automatic below. That is in conflict with the Code Signing Indentity you set above that option.

Try to set Code Signing Style to Manual.

Usually I prefer to set Provisioning Profile and Automatic/Manual signing style in General tab.